# adding dynamic image to table column does not work in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, image, dynamic

I'm new to angulajs and I'm trying to dynamically add image to a column when user selects it.
Here is the below code and it did not work.
code in .cshtml file ---

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img ng-src="{{path}}" />
                <input type="file" ng-model="path" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Code in angularjs file

```
$scope.path = "";
```

I came across 1 example but written in jquery and this what exactly i need it.
http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/4FGg8/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, which looks quiet straight forward. I would recommend not to get into any plugin. [Check this plukr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0VTojPwBsxV9cS45i3MV?p=preview)

```
  $scope.imageUpload = function(event){
   var files = event.target.files; 
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded; 
   reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  }

  $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.path = e.target.result;
   });
  }
```

and in your `html`

```
<input type="file" ng-model="path" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(event)"/>
```

**NOTE:** : `ng-change` is not supported for type `file`

Comment: me using VS2015 as editor and it did not work..giving error

Comment: What error ? Did you check my plnkr ? Is it what you wanted ? Update the question with `VS2015` error

Comment: Why is it related to VS2015?

Comment: it can't be IDE related issue. Share the image of error

Comment: @Shashank Vivek - this is exactly what i want it.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it worked. and share the error screenshot so that I can help you on that as well

Comment: @Shashank Vivek  - error is " JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'imageUpload'". After selecting the image file this error comes.

Comment: Whats the angularJs version ?

Comment: angularjs version 2

Comment: There is no version 2 in angular Js. There is angularjs 1.x or “angular” 2/4/5/6. Both are different. Clarify your statement plz

Comment: @Sia: Awesome ! what was the issue ?

Comment: @Shashank Vivek - reference to file was missing. Hence was getting error. 1 more question.. can we do multiple selection of image files  ?

Comment: Yes, we get `var files = event.target.files; ` as array of files. Try to iterate over it and pass accordingly in `reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);` rather than `files[0]` . Try and let me know if it worked ;)