# How can I catch the "file selected" event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have the following dialog box in my [application](https://github.com/dpisarenko/fileUploadProblem):

[image: Dialog box]

When the user presses the `Add logo` button, following things should happen:

1. A file selectio dialog should pop up.
2. After the user has selected the file, a function should be called (which will update the image).

I have the following code for this. The [markup](https://github.com/dpisarenko/fileUploadProblem/blob/master/app/index.html) for file selection looks like this:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="$ctrl.addLogo()">Add logo</button>
```

`$ctrl.addLogo()` is defined as ([source](https://github.com/dpisarenko/fileUploadProblem/blob/master/app/app.js))

```
$ctrl.addLogo = function() {
    console.log("'Add logo' button clicked");
    var uploadForm = document.createElement('form');
        var fileInput = uploadForm.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    fileInput.type = 'file';
        fileInput.name = 'images';
    fileInput.multiple = true;
        fileInput.click(function() {
        console.log("Click callback called");
    });
};
```

When I press the `Add logo` button, the file selection dialog does open, but the `Click callback called` message does not appear in the console. This means that I cannot detect, when the user has selected a file (or closed the dialog box with "Cancel").

How can I implement a reaction to the user selecting a file (or cancelling the dialog)?

Comment: I think you must use the `onchange` event on the file input instead of `onclick` and this should do the job ;)

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768049/adding-dynamic-image-to-table-column-does-not-work-in-angularjs/49768288#49768288 will help you. Or you can create a directive . I created something similar to watch file changes https://github.com/shashankvivek/RichTextEditor/blob/master/js/directive/file.watcher.dir.js

Comment: @sjahan Thanks. Your comment was helpful. If you submit it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user selects a file in an `input` with `type="file"`, it is the `change` event that is fired.

If you replace your `click` listener by a `change` listener, it should work :)

```
fileInput.click(function() {
    console.log("Click callback called");
});
```

must become:

```
fileInput.change(function() {
    console.log("Click callback called");
});
```