# multiple instance of input type file loads same image

Tags: angularjs, image, dynamic, input-type-file

I have a table and for each row, need to upload image/photo for it. Photo column can have multiple images for single row.

Here is the issue, whenever I tap on browse button for 1st or any row, the images are upload for all other rows also even. I have attached the screenshot of it.

[image]

Code for html part is below :

```
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th align="center">First</th>
            <th align="center">Last</th>
            <th align="center">Age</th>
            <th align="center">photo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td >
                <input type="file" multiple file-upload /> 
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <div ng-repeat="step in files">
                    <img ng-src="{{step.src}}" class="thumbnail" height="50px" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td>aa</td>
            <td>aa</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td >
                <input type="file" multiple file-upload /> 
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <div ng-repeat="step in files">
                    <img ng-src="{{step.src}}" class="thumbnail" height="50px" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>bb</td>
            <td>bb</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td >
                <input type="file" multiple file-upload /> 
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <div ng-repeat="step in files">
                    <img ng-src="{{step.src}}" class="thumbnail" height="50px" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td>cc</td>
            <td>cc</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td >
                <input type="file" multiple file-upload /> 
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <div ng-repeat="step in files">
                    <img ng-src="{{step.src}}" class="thumbnail" height="50px" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Reference for adding dynamic images to table is taken from this link
[adding dynamic image to table column does not work in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768049/adding-dynamic-image-to-table-column-does-not-work-in-angularjs)

Code for angularjs part is below:

```
$scope.files = [];
    $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
        var r = "d";
        var item = args;
        $scope.files.push(item);
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                item.src = reader.result;
            });
        }, false);

        if (item.file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(item.file);
        }
    });

    $scope.path = '';
    $scope.path2 = '';

    $scope.imageUpload = function (event) {
        console.log(event)
        var files = event.target.files;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }
    }

abapp.directive('fileUpload', function () {
    return {
        scope: true, //create a new scope
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    //emit event upward
                    scope.$emit("fileSelected", {
                        file: files[i]
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Well, you do have `ng-repeat step in files` for each. So I assume you have 'files' on your scope and always use the same. You need to loop through rows and for each row have name, lastname, age and multiple files in your data model

Answer (score 0):

On your `$scope` object, you need to have (instead of files variable) something like this:

```
$scope.users = [
    {
        name: "John",
        lastname: "smith",
        age: 11,
        files: [ //this is array of files for this user ]
    }, { 
        name: " Another guy"
        ...
        files: [//this is array of files for another guy]
    }
]
```

And then, loop over users (for each  -> one user).

Comment: - files for each row are loaded dynamically.

Comment: Negative. They are first pushed into `$scope.files[]` and from there distributed thorough the app. As @obey mentioned. Because every table row is signed to look for change in files by `ng-repeat="step in files"`.